# API gateway not connecting with reverse proxy WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am having some challenges trying to get a reverse proxy working with the API gateway. I have configured all the UI components and things are working well with the reverse proxy. I have configured the API locally and it works...but I can't find any documentation on setting up a gateway proxy. I've tried creating several gateway environments using a number of configuration and the best I can get is

> Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL.

Anybody successfully implemented this? I want the proxy endpoint to be on 443 to avoid any port modifications. Whenever I publish the API it wants to use 8280 on the backend...just not sure what to do and there are no examples or docs anywhere I can find.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using as a reverse proxy? is it NGINX?
If you are using NGINX, you have to configure Nginx.conf as follows to expose API gateway.

```
upstream sslgw.am.wso2.com {
    server 127.0.0.1:8243;
    server 127.0.0.1:8244;
    #ip_hash;
}    

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name gw.am.wso2.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.17.7/ssl/nginxLab.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.17.7/ssl/nginxLb.key;
    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_read_timeout 5m;
            proxy_send_timeout 5m;
            proxy_pass https://sslgw.am.wso2.com;
        }

        #access_log /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.17.7/log/gw/https/access.log;
        #error_log /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.17.7/log/gw/https/error.log;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ujitha, Thanks very much for the response. I understand what you are suggesting, but the challenge that I am facing is that when I configure a gateway through the API manager...it sets the ports to 8243|8280 etc. Therefore whenever the API is published to the Developer portal the endpoint will have a port as part of the URI. If I put 443 in the configuration then it will hit the proxy correctly, but when proxy to the backend it will 404.

Comment: I was running an Azure VM with an NGINX server as a reverse proxy for WSO2 Identity Server and got a lot of errors. Tried various solutions but only this worked! Using these settings in the NGINX conf fixed my issues and now the identity server is accessible via https. Thanks, Ujitha!